# 手に入りにくいことは and 自分のものにしよう

Tags: translation

けれどその「不便さ」がある意味では、情報の意味をゆっくり考える猶予を与えてくれていたとも言える。また、**ある種の情報が手に入りにくいことは、それを獲得し自分のものにしようとする強い動機づけになってもいた。**

May I know the meaning of the bolded sentence? 
I know the first sentence means "Inconvenience lets us think about the meaning of the information slowly".  But what is meant by the bolded one?  Something like some information is difficult to obtain and strong motivation to obtain the information? But I can't connect the two parts together into a sentence that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

I changed your translation to "Some kind of information is difficult to obtain, and which became strong motivation to obtain and possess the information." "which" means the sentence "Some information is difficult to obtain". Does it make sense?